# Highchart timeseries group data daily/weekly tooltip formatter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I'm using Highstocks with data grouping turned on by default.

When handling the "point -> events -> mouseOver" event, 
I want to found the exact x-y location of the hovered point.

What I am doing right now is:

```
// When data is grouped as daily/weekly
tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        hideDelay: 0,
        snap: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
        formatter: function() {
          let item;
          // When zoomed out and data is grouped or graph grouped by day or week
          if(this.series.hasGroupedData) {
            // let xPos = this.series.xData[Math.round(this.point.clientX)];
            // let yPos = this.series.yData[Math.round(this.point.plotY)];
            // find the timestamp in the middle of the timestamp grouping
            let maxClientX = Math.round(this.series.groupedData[this.series.groupedData.length - 1].clientX);
            let point_position_percent = this.point.clientX / maxClientX;
            let point_position_index = Math.round(point_position_percent * this.series.xData.length);
            let xPos = this.series.xData[point_position_index];
            item = _.find(this.series.options.data, {x:xPos});
          }
          // When zoomed in
          else {
            item = this.point;
          }
          let tooltipFormat = this.key+'<table><tr><td><span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span></td><td>'+this.series.name+': </td>' + '<td><b>'+this.y+'</b></td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td></td><td>Data 1: </td>' + '<td><b>'+item.data1+'</b></td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td></td><td>Data 2: </td>' + '<td><b>'+item.data2+'</b></td></tr>' +
            '<tr><td></td><td>Data 3: </td>' + '<td><b>'+item.data3+'</b></td></tr></table>';
          return tooltipFormat;
        }
      }
```

It works by simply finding the 'percentage' of the point on the X axis, then converting this percentage to the equivalent index in the data set.

Comment: can you add fiddle, show your data example, and where exactly you put this part? Your if else statement doesn't give much information, if you want help try to provide as much as you can.

Comment: @pegla updated the question, I want the extra data e.g. data1, data2 should be available on each point hover but as it is grouped data I am having problem while getting the exact x-y axis of the point.

Comment: @Ni3 In each grouped point (`this` in `point.events.mouseOver` event) you can find `dataGroup` object, which contains information about how many points are grouped and index of the first raw data point in the group (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/Point.dataGroup). Having that, and using `series.xData` and `series.yData`, which contain `x` and `y` values of raw points, you can add information of any point. If this is not what you wanted, provide us with fully working example, otherwise it will be hard to help you.